# Condition if sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    SI_Num_Inventario = COALESCE (t.SI_Num_Inventario, c.SI_Num_Inventario),
    SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion),
    SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica, c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica),
    SI_Num_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo),
    NULL,
    SI_Num_Conteo = COALESCE(cs.SI_Num_Conteo,2),
    GETDATE(),
    'Admin',
    c.SI_OV 
FROM 
    SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
FULL JOIN 
    SI_Conteo c ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo
                AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion 
INNER JOIN 
    SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
                         OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
FULL JOIN 
    SI_Consecutivo cs ON c.SI_Num_Inventario = cs.SI_Num_Inventario
                      AND cs.SI_Estado = 0
WHERE 
    c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201423 OR t.SI_Articulo = 201423
```

And I'm trying to tell you that if c.SI_OV IS NULL INSERT THIS `INSERT INTO``

```
IF c.SI_OV IS NULL
    INSERT INTO SI_Conteo(SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Ubicacion,SI_Num_Articulo, SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo, SI_Usuario,SI_OV)
```

And if it is not NULL insert me this other

```
ELSE
    INSERT INTO SI_Conteo(SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Ubicacion_Fisica, SI_Num_Articulo, SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo, SI_Usuario,SI_OV)
END IF;
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: How do I do `if` ` else`

Comment: @Eduard didn't read much of the question but and if else statement is akin to a CASE WHEN in SQL.

Comment: How do I do with a case when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: the `CASE` construct needs to "live" in your `SELECT` clause of you SQL statement. The receiving `INSERT` clause should always mention *both* column names like this

```
INSERT INTO SI_CONTEO (SI_Num_Inventario, 
  SI_Ubicacion, SI_Ubicacion_fisico,
  SI_Num_Articulo, SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,
  SI_Fecha_Conteo, SI_Usuario,SI_OV)
SELECT SI_Num_Inventario = COALESCE (t.SI_Num_Inventario,c.SI_Num_Inventario),
  SI_Ubicacion = CASE WHEN SI_OV IS NULL THEN COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion) END,
  SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = CASE WHEN NOT SU_OV IS NULL THEN COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica, c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica) END,
  SI_Num_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo), 
  NULL, ...
```

Comment: It seems I was a few seconds too slow with my answer. Well, that is what happens when you try to answer questions using a smartphone ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if else in non query language  ~= CASE WHEN cond1 ELSE cond2 END in SQL

Comment: But as I do with the select and insert into?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you insert into a table based on a case when? I'm not sure as I've never tried, maybe? Otherwise you can dump to a temporary table and insert after that is made.

Comment: @user1352683 No, if/else is a control of flow construct in tsql, just like it is in the vast majority of other languages. CASE is a scalar expression in tsql, **unlike** most other languages were it (CASE) is a control of flow construct similar to a series of nested IF statements.

Comment: @SMor I'm not really sure what you are saying -- but I thought he was looking for an if else equivalent in SQL. CASE WHEN was the best I could think of for that and at least to my knowledge it is the most analogous thing in sql

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
INSERT INTO SI_Conteo(SI_Num_Inventario,SI_Ubicacion,SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,SI_Num_Articulo, SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo,
SI_Usuario,SI_OV)
SELECT 
SI_Num_Inventario = COALESCE (t.SI_Num_Inventario,c.SI_Num_Inventario),
(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NULL THEN  COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion) ELSE NULL END)AS SI_Ubicacion,
(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN  COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica, c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica) ELSE NULL END)AS SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,
SI_Num_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo),
NULL,
SI_Num_Conteo = COALESCE(cs.SI_Num_Conteo,2),
GETDATE(),
'Admin',
c.SI_OV 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
full JOIN SI_Conteo c
ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo
AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion 
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m 
ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
FULL JOIN SI_Consecutivo cs
ON  c.SI_Num_Inventario = cs.SI_Num_Inventario
AND cs.SI_Estado = 0
WHERE c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201423 OR t.SI_Articulo = 201423
```

Basicallly I have combined both inserts into one Insert, which includes both of the columns , where you want a switch based on Case. Only one column out of SI_Ubicacion and SI_Ubicacion_Fisica will be set based on s.SI_OV value. Hope you got what I am saying,.

Note: I Could not execute this as I don't have any table structure/data with me. I have modified your query manually and posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

Clarify your question. You have a select statement that returns a resultset of some number of rows. You propose to insert them into a table. You claim to need to use if/else (or similar) but it is not clear why. Your proposed insert statements differ by a single column - is that correct? If so, then you probably need to use 2 different insert statements - one to handle the non-null situation and one to handle the null situation. You cannot dynamically change the column list of the inserted table.

OTOH, perhaps you just want to swap the value inserted into the SI_Ubicacion column of the SI_Conteo table? If so, you can probably use isnull or coalesce in the select statement (much like you do now - just differently).